# HTML looks different on different computers

Tags: html, codepen

I'm coding a website in CodePen and I've been working on it on my laptop (Macbook Air 13") and so I've been setting my parameters to look good on that size screen apparently, because when I opened up my same code on my Mac Desktop, things were not aligned the way and I needed them to be. I'm using Chrome and CodePen on both computers. How can I get the same render?

Comment: Hey Bob, Welcome to StackOverflow(SO), please post some code you tried or create a replica of your issue using SO snippet. Also you might need to know more about Responsive Design, that would help you out for your issue. Here look into this https://responsivedesign.is/

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the different Screen size and screen resolutions of your devices.You need to add media queries to align the content according to your need.

Have a look - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your UI code is not Responsive. Try making it responsive with all devices..
For this you can use BootStrap.
You can learn from here: [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp